# Is it bad to expose database internals?

Tags: mongodb, database

I've been told that it's bad to expose database internals but I've started noticing lots of relatively high profile sites doing it, e.g. Chartboost and ServerDensity both expose the MongoDB document `_id` field in their URLs.

Can someone shed some light as to why that's bad to do? The only thing I can think of is that it's bad for SEO because they're not human readable URLs, but is this even true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "exposing database internals" I understand stuff like exposing the database server to the internet or letting user run arbitrary queries. This stuff is unquestionably bad. Or, if you somehow expose your database schema, a malicious user can use this to his advantage.

Using object ids in urls is fine. Humans do not memorize urls anyway, and search engines don't care if link to a post is made of post slug or post id.

Answer (score 1):

Even stackoverflow show its database ID-s in URL. It could be surrogate key or natural, anyway you have to identify resource somehow. Basically, every single site use some kind of identification in URL, usually PK. Why do you think they use MongoDb ? It could be even relation database with GUID instead of Long PK

Even if you show someone database schema, nothing will happen, until you are protected from sql-injection.

Comment: But SO's id are not DB specific, like the mongoDB _id

Comment: what is DB specific IDs ? I do not see any reason to convert surrogate or natural PK from database to special "not specific" ID

Comment: Db specific, meaning by default they're not just an auto-increment, guid, or any other generally used DB identifier.  The default MongoDB ObjectId contains, at least, the date the record was created, an identifier of the machine that created the document, and identifies the db used behind the app.  Of course, you can chose to replace _id with your own identifer type, in which case it's the same situation as SO.